Multiprocessing error after trying to train with YOLOv8
My terminal returns the following when i attempt to train my model:
import ultralytics 
import torch 
from ultralytics import YOLO 

print(torch.cuda.is_available()) 
# Load a model 
model = YOLO("best.pt") 
# Use the model 
model.train(data="config.yaml", epochs=10, device="cpu",mixup=0.5,copy_paste=0.5,translate=0.2,scale=0.2) # train the model

Ultralytics YOLOv8.2.5  Python-3.11.7 torch-2.3.0 CUDA:0 (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Laptop GPU, 4096MiB)
engine\trainer: task=detect, mode=train, model=yolov8n.yaml, data=config.yaml, epochs=10, time=None, patience=100, batch=16, imgsz=640, save=True, save_period=-1, cache=False, device=None, workers=8, project=None, name=train2, exist_ok=False, pretrained=True, optimizer=auto, verbose=True, seed=0, deterministic=True, single_cls=False, rect=False, cos_lr=False, close_mosaic=10, resume=False, amp=True, fraction=1.0, profile=False, freeze=None, multi_scale=False, overlap_mask=True, mask_ratio=4, dropout=0.0, val=True, split=val, save_json=False, save_hybrid=False, conf=None, iou=0.7, max_det=300, half=False, dnn=False, plots=True, source=None, vid_stride=1, stream_buffer=False, visualize=False, augment=False, agnostic_nms=False, classes=None, retina_masks=False, embed=None, show=False, save_frames=False, save_txt=False, save_conf=False, save_crop=False, show_labels=True, show_conf=True, show_boxes=True, line_width=None, format=torchscript, keras=False, optimize=False, int8=False, dynamic=False, simplify=False, opset=None, workspace=4, nms=False, lr0=0.01, lrf=0.01, momentum=0.937, weight_decay=0.0005, warmup_epochs=3.0, warmup_momentum=0.8, warmup_bias_lr=0.1, box=7.5, cls=0.5, dfl=1.5, pose=12.0, kobj=1.0, label_smoothing=0.0, nbs=64, hsv_h=0.015, hsv_s=0.7, hsv_v=0.4, degrees=0.0, translate=0.1, scale=0.5, shear=0.0, perspective=0.0, flipud=0.0, fliplr=0.5, bgr=0.0, mosaic=1.0, mixup=0.0, copy_paste=0.0, auto_augment=randaugment, erasing=0.4, crop_fraction=1.0, cfg=None, tracker=botsort.yaml, save_dir=runs\detect\train2
Overriding model.yaml nc=80 with nc=1

                   from  n    params  module                                       arguments
  0                  -1  1       464  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [3, 16, 3, 2]
  1                  -1  1      4672  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [16, 32, 3, 2]
  2                  -1  1      7360  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [32, 32, 1, True]
  3                  -1  1     18560  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [32, 64, 3, 2]
  4                  -1  2     49664  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [64, 64, 2, True]
  5                  -1  1     73984  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [64, 128, 3, 2]
  6                  -1  2    197632  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [128, 128, 2, True]
  7                  -1  1    295424  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [128, 256, 3, 2]
  8                  -1  1    460288  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [256, 256, 1, True]
  9                  -1  1    164608  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.SPPF            [256, 256, 5]
 10                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']
 11             [-1, 6]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]
 12                  -1  1    148224  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [384, 128, 1]
 13                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']
 14             [-1, 4]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]
 15                  -1  1     37248  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [192, 64, 1]
 16                  -1  1     36992  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [64, 64, 3, 2]
 17            [-1, 12]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]
 18                  -1  1    123648  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [192, 128, 1]
 19                  -1  1    147712  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [128, 128, 3, 2]
 20             [-1, 9]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]
 21                  -1  1    493056  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [384, 256, 1]
 22        [15, 18, 21]  1    751507  ultralytics.nn.modules.head.Detect           [1, [64, 128, 256]]
YOLOv8n summary: 225 layers, 3011043 parameters, 3011027 gradients, 8.2 GFLOPs

TensorBoard: Start with 'tensorboard --logdir runs\detect\train2', view at http://localhost:6006/
Freezing layer 'model.22.dfl.conv.weight'
AMP: running Automatic Mixed Precision (AMP) checks with YOLOv8n...
AMP: checks passed ✅
train: Scanning C:\Users\Sawyer\Desktop\Code\dataset\labels.cache... 1968 images, 0 backgrounds, 0 corrupt: 100%|██████████| 1968/1968 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Ultralytics YOLOv8.2.5  Python-3.11.7 torch-2.3.0 CUDA:0 (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Laptop GPU, 4096MiB)
engine\trainer: task=detect, mode=train, model=yolov8n.yaml, data=config.yaml, epochs=10, time=None, patience=100, batch=16, imgsz=640, save=True, save_period=-1, cache=False, device=None, workers=8, project=None, name=train3, exist_ok=False, pretrained=True, optimizer=auto, verbose=True, seed=0, deterministic=True, single_cls=False, rect=False, cos_lr=False, close_mosaic=10, resume=False, amp=True, fraction=1.0, profile=False, freeze=None, multi_scale=False, overlap_mask=True, mask_ratio=4, dropout=0.0, val=True, split=val, save_json=False, save_hybrid=False, conf=None, iou=0.7, max_det=300, half=False, dnn=False, plots=True, source=None, vid_stride=1, stream_buffer=False, visualize=False, augment=False, agnostic_nms=False, classes=None, retina_masks=False, embed=None, show=False, save_frames=False, save_txt=False, save_conf=False, save_crop=False, show_labels=True, show_conf=True, show_boxes=True, line_width=None, format=torchscript, keras=False, optimize=False, int8=False, dynamic=False, simplify=False, opset=None, workspace=4, nms=False, lr0=0.01, lrf=0.01, momentum=0.937, weight_decay=0.0005, warmup_epochs=3.0, warmup_momentum=0.8, warmup_bias_lr=0.1, box=7.5, cls=0.5, dfl=1.5, pose=12.0, kobj=1.0, label_smoothing=0.0, nbs=64, hsv_h=0.015, hsv_s=0.7, hsv_v=0.4, degrees=0.0, translate=0.1, scale=0.5, shear=0.0, perspective=0.0, flipud=0.0, fliplr=0.5, bgr=0.0, mosaic=1.0, mixup=0.0, copy_paste=0.0, auto_augment=randaugment, erasing=0.4, crop_fraction=1.0, cfg=None, tracker=botsort.yaml, save_dir=runs\detect\train3
Overriding model.yaml nc=80 with nc=1

                   from  n    params  module                                       arguments
  0                  -1  1       464  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [3, 16, 3, 2]
  1                  -1  1      4672  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [16, 32, 3, 2]
  2                  -1  1      7360  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [32, 32, 1, True]
  3                  -1  1     18560  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [32, 64, 3, 2]
  4                  -1  2     49664  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [64, 64, 2, True]
  5                  -1  1     73984  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [64, 128, 3, 2]
  6                  -1  2    197632  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [128, 128, 2, True]
  7                  -1  1    295424  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [128, 256, 3, 2]
  8                  -1  1    460288  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [256, 256, 1, True]
  9                  -1  1    164608  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.SPPF            [256, 256, 5]
 10                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']
 11             [-1, 6]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]
 12                  -1  1    148224  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [384, 128, 1]
 13                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']
 14             [-1, 4]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]
 15                  -1  1     37248  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [192, 64, 1]
 16                  -1  1     36992  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [64, 64, 3, 2]
 17            [-1, 12]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]
 18                  -1  1    123648  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [192, 128, 1]
 19                  -1  1    147712  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [128, 128, 3, 2]
 20             [-1, 9]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]
 21                  -1  1    493056  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [384, 256, 1]
 22        [15, 18, 21]  1    751507  ultralytics.nn.modules.head.Detect           [1, [64, 128, 256]]
YOLOv8n summary: 225 layers, 3011043 parameters, 3011027 gradients, 8.2 GFLOPs

TensorBoard: Start with 'tensorboard --logdir runs\detect\train3', view at http://localhost:6006/
Freezing layer 'model.22.dfl.conv.weight'
AMP: running Automatic Mixed Precision (AMP) checks with YOLOv8n...
AMP: checks passed ✅
train: Scanning C:\Users\Sawyer\Desktop\Code\dataset\labels.cache... 1968 images, 0 backgrounds, 0 corrupt: 100%|██████████| 1968/1968 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Sawyer\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 122, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sawyer\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 131, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\Sawyer\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 246, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\Sawyer\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 297, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 291, in run_path
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 98, in _run_module_code
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "c:\Users\Sawyer\Desktop\Code\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    model.train(data="config.yaml", epochs=10)  # train the model
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sawyer\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\model.py", line 673, in train
    self.trainer.train()
  File "C:\Users\Sawyer\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\trainer.py", line 199, in train
    self._do_train(world_size)
  File "C:\Users\Sawyer\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\trainer.py", line 313, in _do_train
    self._setup_train(world_size)
  File "C:\Users\Sawyer\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\trainer.py", line 277, in _setup_train
    self.train_loader = self.get_dataloader(self.trainset, batch_size=batch_size, rank=RANK, mode="train")
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sawyer\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\models\yolo\detect\train.py", line 55, in get_dataloader
    return build_dataloader(dataset, batch_size, workers, shuffle, rank)  # return dataloader
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sawyer\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\data\build.py", line 137, in build_dataloader
    return InfiniteDataLoader(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sawyer\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\data\build.py", line 41, in __init__
    self.iterator = super().__iter__()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sawyer\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 439, in __iter__
    return self._get_iterator()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sawyer\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 387, in _get_iterator
    return _MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sawyer\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 1040, in __init__
    w.start()
  File "C:\Users\Sawyer\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sawyer\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sawyer\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 336, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sawyer\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 46, in __init__
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sawyer\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 164, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "C:\Users\Sawyer\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 140, in _check_not_importing_main
    raise RuntimeError('''
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

        To fix this issue, refer to the "Safe importing of main module"
        section in https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Im not sure what the problem is and cannot seem to figure it out. I dont exactly understand what the RuntimeError is telling me ethier, please help. :(
I tried looking at spawn.py with no results, other than that I have no idea where to start when solving this problem.

It will be helpful to share the train code you run

import ultralytics
import torch
from ultralytics import YOLO
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
Load a model
model = YOLO("best.pt")  # build a new model from scratch
Use the model
model.train(data="config.yaml", epochs=10, device="cpu",mixup=0.5,copy_paste=0.5,translate=0.2,scale=0.2)  # train the model

that's what I run to start training my model, if that is what you were referring to. Currently, it runs on my cpu without any issues, but if my GPU is used it breaks.

If you are running this code in Windows, this issue can appear due to the way the multiprocessing module is initialized in Windows environments. The following  solution is provided by Ultralytics:

Python's multiprocessing requires a specific if-statement guard in scripts that are using the multiprocessing functionalities to avoid recursion in Windows. To correct this issue in your code, you'll want to wrap your training call in an if name == 'main': block. Essentially, this ensures that your training only begins if your script is run as the main program. It prevents the recursive importing that's happening when using multiprocessing on Windows.

from ultralytics import YOLO

if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = YOLO('best.pt')
    model.train(data="config.yaml", epochs=10, device="CPU", mixup=0.5, copy_paste=0.5, translate=0.2, scale=0.2)


This is also in the multiprocessing docs that are linked in the error message OP originally posted...

Now I see)) Have you tried this?

oh my god....Im dumb. I should have done this faster. Thank you for the answer, this works now on my gpu. you are a lifesaver.
